# Change vertical space before \chapter and \thebibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, chapters, scrbook

I'm using the `scrbook`-class and changed the `\chapter`-settings to:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=16.5cm,%\dimexpr3.3\baselineskip+1\parskip\relax,,
innerskip=.5cm,%
afterskip=1.725\baselineskip plus .115\baselineskip minus .192\baselineskip
]{chapter}
\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\raggedleft}
\renewcommand\chapterformat{{\fontsize{100pt}{80pt}\selectfont\textcolor{DeepSkyBlue}{\thechapter}}}
\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
    {\fontsize{30}{40}\selectfont\color{DimGray}#2#3}%
    \vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}% 
}%
```

which adds 16.5cm of space befor the chapter. However, the same amount of space is addes if i use `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and before the `thebibliography` environment,which .
How can I selectively change only the vertical space of `\chapter` and not affect the other commands?

Comment: Those are chapters as well.

Comment: You csn redeclare the chapter command several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
\BeforeTOCHead{\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-3.3\baselineskip minus -\parskip]{chapter}}
```

you can change `beforeskip` for the TOC and all lists controlled by package `tocbasic`, eg. LOT and LOF.

Environment `thebibliography` can be patched by

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\thebibliography
  {\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-3.3\baselineskip minus -\parskip]{chapter}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
```

But depending on the order of TOC, LOF, LOT, bibliography and the numbered chapters it could be better to change `beforeskip` before first numbered chapters. There is no MWE in your question ...

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Works just perfect.